# Blueprintjs: Hotkey input

Tags: blueprintjs

I'm currently trying to do UI that allow me to enter hotkeys for different table rows...

So main idea is to make something like editableCell, where i will input hotkeys.

I already found getKeyComboString method from docs:
http://blueprintjs.com/docs/#core/components/hotkeys.key-combos

But my problem is: how i make something like EditableCell double click ?

i looked in source and found, that editableCell uses Draggable component for this (as i can say), but i can't import it.
so i don't know how should i check if my input looses focus...

Any ideas how to make hotkey input ?

Answer (score 0):

I'v done this using onBlur event and `isEditing` state.

```
        <div
            className={className}
            onDoubleClick={this.handleCellDoubleClick}
            onBlur={this.handleBlur}
            onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
            tabIndex={0}
        >
            {this.state.keyCombo} 
        </div>
```

onDoubleClick set state to `isEditing: true`

onBlur set it to false

onKeyDown works only when `isEditing: true`